# Getting current Product ID with Shopify API for a Javascript API call

Tags: shopify

I'm toying with developing a Shopify App that uses the DaisyAPI dynamic image service for Shopify. In order to make the correct call to the Daisy API, I need to know what Product the customer is looking at. It seems like, to reliably do that, I will need to manipulate their product.liquid theme to insert a hidden value containing the Product ID so that Jquery can pick up that value and insert it into the API call.

What's the best way to ensure every product page contains the product ID in such a way jQuery can reliably find it? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing a very obvious and cool Liquid filter.

In Liquid, pump the Object for it's JSON.

```
var p = {{ product | json }};
```

And then go to town... you cannot go far on the client without this concept. Get the JSON man.. get the JSON...

Comment: Thanks David- With that technique, would I have to ask each of my App Customers to manipulate their Liquid file manually? Or is their a way to do that through the API?

Or does Shopify parse Liquid tags even on externally loaded Javascript files?

Comment: You can read their product.liquid file, copy it to your own (say product.customized.liquid), edit yours to make it work sweet, and then add yours to their shop, and then just instruct them to use your special product.customized.liquid.

When they uninstall your App, they are left with your Liquid sitting around their shop.. but that is easy to delete... and easy for them to re-wire back to whatever they want.

Comment: David- Many thanks for your help. One more question- The API Docs don't mention anything about getting or putting individual .liquid files. It appears I can upload an entirely new theme as a .zip file, but that's it. Is there a .liquid file method in the API I'm missing?

Comment: Why you no upvote my answer? You are dealing with Assets when you deal with Liquid files... take a look at the Asset part of the API.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I no upvote answer because I so excited about getting the JSON!

Answer (score 17):

Another option would be to use the Ajax API to request the product. Of you know you're on a product page simple make a request to the same URL and append .json. You will then have a json representation of the product that you can do whatever yo want with.

To get you js into the theme you can use a script tag which will load js from you server onto the shop.

Comment: Hi John- Thanks for your help, That's a great trick, didn't think of that!

Comment: +1 for mentioning you can do the json trick to a product page.